# Django Import-Export Overwriting / Updating non-unique CharField

Tags: python, django, database

I am trying to import xls files that in some cases have missing data. Rather than manually changing the necessary fields before import, I'd ideally like Django to account for them.

In this case, while each product should have a unique barcode, some products in this xls file have 'N/A' instead. For some reason Django is interpreting these products as the same, and updates them instead of creating new.

[image: Import Image]

This problem does not occur for the other CharFields like Format or Cost; if all entries have a Format of 'LP' the import proceeds without error.

Any ideas what is causing this?

Bonus Question: Any way to chop off the time from the Release Date?

I believe this is all the relevant code.

resources.py

```
class ArtistWidget(widgets.ForeignKeyWidget):
    def clean(self, value, row=None, *arg, **kwargs):
        return self.model.objects.get_or_create(artist=value)[0] if value else None


class LabelWidget(widgets.ForeignKeyWidget):
    def clean(self, value, row=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.model.objects.get_or_create(label=value)[0] if value else None


class ProductResource(resources.ModelResource):
    artist = fields.Field(column_name='artist', attribute='artist',
                          widget=ArtistWidget(Artist, 'artist'))
    label = fields.Field(column_name='label', attribute='label',
                         widget=LabelWidget(Label, 'label'))
    prod_format = fields.Field(column_name='format', attribute='prod_format')
    release_date = fields.Field(
        column_name='release date', attribute='release_date')
    cat_number = fields.Field(column_name='cat#', attribute="cat_number")

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        import_id_fields = ('barcode',)
        fields = ('artist', 'title', 'cat_number',
                  'prod_format', 'label', 'barcode', 'cost', 'release_date',)
        skip_unchanged = True
        export_order = ['artist', 'title', 'cat_number',
                        'prod_format', 'label', 'barcode', 'cost', 'release_date', ]

    def before_import_row(self, row, **kwargs):
        # Convert Excel Date to datetime
        row['release date'] = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(
            row['release date'], datemode=0))
        # String Conversions
        row['artist'] = string.capwords(row['artist'])
        row['title'] = string.capwords(row['title'])
        row['label'] = row['label'].upper()
```

models.py

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=30)


class Label(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(primary_key=True, unique=True, max_length=30)


class Product(models.Model):
    barcode = models.CharField(
        'UPC/Barcode', max_length=20, blank=True, unique=False)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    sub_title = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    release_date = models.DateField('Release Date', blank=True)
    prod_format = models.CharField('Format', max_length=12)
    label = models.ForeignKey(Label, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    cat_number = models.CharField(
        'Catalogue Number', max_length=12, blank=True)
    cost = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True)
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to _"...chop off the time from the Release Date?"_ ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it was only accepting unique fields in the barcode column was this setting in the resource:

`import_id_fields = ('barcode',)`

I created a Barcode Widget together with the rstr module to create random 8-digit barcodes to replace the 'n/a':

```
class BarcodeWidget(widgets.CharWidget):
    def clean(self, value, row=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if value == 'n/a':
            value = rstr.rstr(string.digits, 8)
            return value
        else:
            return value
```

```
class ProductResource(resources.ModelResource):
    barcode = fields.Field(column_name='barcode',
                           attribute='barcode', widget=BarcodeWidget())
```